# What's the correct way to sneeze?

Tags: nose, sneeze-sneezing

I know this sounds like a joke question (and while i'm sure it's funny) it's not a joke.  I have always sneezed "weird" and many people can't tell the difference between my sneezes and coughs.  I always sneeze 3-10 times in a row, and I have some allergies but nothing extreme.  My whole family does the multiple sneeze thing.

Anyways, I've always sneezed with my mouth open, but lately I've been trying it with my mouth closed.  There's two ways to do it, stifle the sneeze or let it fly out the nose.

Is there anything I'm missing?  How do you guys sneeze?  Also wondering if anyone else sneezes a bunch of times in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, make sure you cover your mouth with e.g. the inside of your elbow.
Spreading bugs is a) bad, and b) impolite.

[See this CDC webpage for more information.](https://www.cdc.gov/healthywater/hygiene/etiquette/coughing_sneezing.html)

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Comment: Hi. Sorry. Removed my speculation. FWIW your link to the list of reliable sources appears to be incorrect.

Comment: Scroll down, the first answer is the list. Thanks for the edit, +1 from me!

Comment: Got it now. Sorry, must have looked at the wrong link.